# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (5, 54)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am implementing a lstm model with keras.

There are 11200 lines in my dataset and 5 columns. Each data is a vector. The shape of the dataset is (11200, 5, 54) and it looks like this.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5

[1,3,...,-999] [2,4,...,-999] [3,4,...,-999] [5,6,...,-999] [4,5,...,-999]

[0,2,...,-999] [1,5,...,-999] [1,24,...,-999] [11,7,...,-999] [-1,4,...,-999]

...

[0,2,...,5] [1,5,...,8] [1,24,...,6] [11,7,...,5] [-1,4,...,2]
```

The length of each vector like this one [1,3,...,-999] is 54.

The target is a boolean vector of size (11200, 1) like this

```
1      T

2      F

...    ...

11200  F
```

I created my model like this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data,target, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)  
batch_size = 32 
timesteps = None 
output_size = 1
epochs=120

inputs = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, output_size))
lay1 = LSTM(20, stateful=True, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
output = Dense(units = output_size)(lay1)
regressor = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs = output)
regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'mae')
regressor.summary()

for i in range(epochs):
    print("Epoch: " + str(i))
    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, shuffle=False, epochs = 1, batch_size = batch_size)
    regressor.reset_states()
```

The problem is I have this error :

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (5, 54).
```

What is wrong? The input or the output ? How can I feed the wrong one ?

Thanks.

Comment: you have `timesteps = None` but you feed 5 to it, try to change `timesteps` to **0**

Comment: I did not feed anything. This is my previous question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50331324/deep-learning-lstm-with-keras-and-variable-size-of-inputs.

Comment: Ok I did what you told me but now I have this error : ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for 'lstm_1/strided_slice_13' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [0,30,1], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.

Comment: `inputs = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, output_size))`
which is the same as
`inputs = Input(batch_shape=(32, None, 1))`

Try changing Timesteps to 5, and output_size to 54. Though why you have output_size as input, I'm not sure.

Comment: I use a tutorial from coursera and the link to the code is: https://github.com/romeokienzler/developerWorks/blob/master/coursera/ai/week3/lstm_crude_oil_price_prediction.ipynb. Yes I did try with timesteps = 5 but I still have ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (5, 1) but got array with shape (5, 54). So I think I need to reshape my output vector. I was thinking with an array of 54 (0,..,0,1) for True and (0,..,0,0) for False. But it does not feel like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the shape of the `Input` layer:

```
inputs = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, output_size)) # output_size = 1
```

where you need it the final dimension to be 54 instead of `output_size` so `batch_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, 54)`. Having `timesteps=None` is not a problem, if you fix to 5 it will allow you to optionally unroll the LSTM which might speed up computation. Otherwise, it says for some unknown number of timesteps, in your case it is 5.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what needs to be 54. What do I need to change ?

Comment: Apologies, I've notices that is unclear. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks I got it ! But do I need to reshape the output ('target' in my case) ? Because its shape is (11200,1). And now I have another issue : ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (11200, 1).

Comment: Ah, that is because you `return_sequence=True` which returns LSTM output at every timestep. Presumably you don't want and want the LSTM to summarise the input into a single vector.

Comment: Also, are you confident that you need `stateful=True`? Only used if your data is linked across batches, often it is not necessary to use stateful.